# Do the non-units in a commutative ring form an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Do the non-units in a commutative ring form an ideal?

The following are my thoughts on this. Have I made any incorrect assumptions?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $a, b \in N$ with $N$ being the set of non-units in $R$. We must show the following to prove $N$ is an ideal -

1. $0 \in N$
2. $a + b \in N$
3. $-a \in N$
4. $ar, ra \in N \ \forall r \in R$

**1.**  $0 \in N$

I.e. $0$ a non-unit. This is true as $\nexists \ 0^{-1}$ such that $0 \cdot 0^{-1} = 1$

**2.** $a + b \in N$

Assume $a + b$ is a unit. Then $\exists \ g \in R$, $g \neq 0$ such that

$(a + b)g = 1$ $\implies$ $ag + bg = 1$

For this to be true either $a$ or $b$ must be $0$. Consider the case when $a = 0$. Then we have $bg = 1$. But this is a contradiction as $b$ is a non-unit. Hence $\nexists \ g \in R$ such that $(a + b)g = 1$. Similarly for when $b = 0$.

Therefore, $a + b$ is a non-unit.

**3.** $-a \in N$

I.e. Does there exist $(-a) \in N$ such that $a + (-a) = 0$?

Assume $-a$ is a unit. Then $\exists \ g \in R, g \neq$ 0, such that $(-a)g = 1$

Consider $a + (-a) = 0$

Multiplying both sides by $g$ we get

$(a + (-a))g = 0 \cdot g$

$ag + (-a)g = 0$

$ag + 1 = 0$

$-ag = 1$

$a(-g) = 1$

But this is a contradiction as $a$ is a non-unit. Hence $(-a)$ is a non-unit.

**4.** $ar, ra \in N \ \forall r \in R$

Assume $ar$ is a unit. Then $\exists \ g \in R, g \neq$ 0, such that $(ar)g = 1$

I.e. $a(gr) = 1$

But this is a contradiction as $a$ is a non-unit. Hence $ar$ is a non-unit.

So, to conclude, the non-units in a commutative ring do form an ideal. Are my workings correct?

Comment: $3 + (-2) = 1$. Your step to show that the sum of non-units is a non-unit is wrong.

Comment: Why are people downvoting the question? It clearly shows work, and it is a legitimate question one might ask.

Comment: Thats not true like @DanielFischer said , but over a commutative ring zero divisors form an ideal .

Comment: @Theorem That is also not true. If the ring has an idempotent $e\notin \{0,1\}$, then $1-e$ and $e$ are zero divisors, and an ideal containing them must contain $1$ also.

Comment: It might help to look at a dramatic example. Consider the field of two elements $F_2$ and look at $\prod_{i\in I} F_2$ where the index set $I$ is as big as you want (but at least bigger than just one element.) What are the units of that ring? And thus what are the nonunits?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Good call: we can use this to remind people that good-faith questions with mistakes don't usually deserve downvotes. Answering such questions is a teaching and learning opportunity! (And Daniel Fischer made good use of it!)

Comment: @rschwieb : Thanks, In commutative ring with only {0,1} as idempotent elements , the zero divisors form an ideal . I hope this statement is true .:)

Comment: Dear @Theorem : No, because $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-1)$ has no nontrivial idempotents,  and has zero divisors $x+1$ and $x-1$. These two add to $2x$, but $2x$ is not a zero divisor in this ring. So the zero divisors here are not closed under addition.

Comment: @Theorem If someone casts doubt on your intuition, try to prove it or scan the net for the result. Don't just revise your guess and hope for the best! (Although you're providing a lot of teaching and learning opportunities here :) )

Comment: @rschwieb : Thank you . I found the fallacy in my argument.Let $I$ be a set of zero divisors of a ring.Then for $r\in R $ and $a\in I$, $r.a$ is also a zero divisor . But the problem seems to be with the group structure of an ideal with respect to addition , let $a\in I , b\in I $ then my thoughts were that $a+b\in I $ , because if $m.a=0$ and $n.b=0 \implies (a+b)m.n=0$ which is true , but that wouldn't tell me that (a+b) is a zero divisor while it could be that $m.n=0$. I would be glad if u could let me know if i have found out the loophole in my reasoning . :)

Comment: @Theorem I think you got it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, the set $N$ of non-units in a commutative ring $R$ doesn't form an ideal. The first point, $0\in N$, fails if and only if $R = \{0\}$ is the trivial ring, in which $0$ is a unit. Points 3. and 4. hold in any commutative ring, and your argument is correct.

However, in general, the sum of non-units need not be a non-unit. In $\mathbb{Z}$ for example, we have $3 + (-2) = 1 \notin N$. A commutative ring in which $N$ is an ideal is a [*local ring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring), a ring with a unique maximal ideal - that ideal is then the set of non-units. An example of a local ring is the ring of formal power series over a field, $K[[X]]$, in which the unique maximal ideal is the ideal generated by $X$.